# Script executed by logrotate gives different result than by executing it manually

Tags: bash, shell-script, logrotate

I want to rotate our application logs using `logrotate`. After each rotation, it executes a script which moves all rotated logs to another directory.
For example in `/home/dev/logs/frontend`, I have these log files:

```bsh
webapp1-access.log
webapp2-access.log
anotherapp3-access.log
codename-access.log
...
```

And my logrotate config file:

```
$ cat app.daily
/home/dev/logs/frontend/*access.log {
   rotate 1
   daily
   copytruncate
   compress
   notifempty
   missingok
   lastaction
      bash /path/to/script.sh
   endscript
}
```

And what script.sh does is to *create a directory based on the log file name* then move the rotated log file there. The `webapp1-access.log` would be rotated to `webapp1-access.log.1.gz` then the script will move it to `/x/y/webbapp1/renamed.log.gz`. And so on for other rotated logs.

When I tested the logrotate using `logrotate -fv /path/to/config`, and It works perfectly as I expected. Then I put the logrotate config file to `/etc/logrotate.d` (as a symlink).

Next day I checked `/x/y` dir, I got:

```
webbapp1/                       <---- created from initial logrotate -fv
webbapp1-access.log/            <---- Unexpected
anotherapp3/                    <---- created from initial logrotate -fv
anotherapp3-access.log/         <---- Unexpected
codename/                       <---- created from initial logrotate -fv
codename-access.log/            <---- Unexpected
```

The `*-access.log/` dirs are created by the logrotate. But running `logrotate -vf config` multiple times wont produce that unexpected result. That happens when I leave logrotate do its daily rotation.

Why is this happening? How can I fix this?

---

`script.sh`

```bsh
#! /usr/bin/bash

exec 3>> /var/log/archived-log.log
[ "${1:-}" = "-d" ] && debug=1

environment="frontend"

rotateddir="/home/dev/logs/$environment"
destdir="/x/y"
[ "${debug:-}" ] && echo "DEST DIR: $destdir"

log() {
    timestamp=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    echo "$timestamp: $1" >&3
}

for archive in $rotateddir/*.gz; do
    [ "${debug:-}" ] && echo "ARCHIVE: $archive"
    [ "${archive##*/}" = "*.gz"  ] && continue
    base_name=$(basename "$archive")
    [ "${debug:-}" ] && echo "BASENAME: $base_name"
    extension="${base_name##*.}"
    [ "${debug:-}" ] && echo "EXT: $extension"
    newdir_name="${base_name%-*}"
    [ "${debug:-}" ] && echo "NEWDIR_NAME: $newdir_name"
    tanggal=$(stat -c %y "$archive" | cut -d" " -f1 | { read dat; date -d $dat +%Y%m%d; })
    #jam=$(stat -c %y "$archive" | cut -d" " -f2 | { read dat; date -d $dat +%H%M; })
    newdir_path="$destdir/$newdir_name"
    [ "${debug:-}" ] && echo "NEWDIR_PATH: $newdir_path"
    #dest_archive="$newdir_path/$tanggal-$jam.log.$extension"
    dest_archive="$newdir_path/$tanggal.log.$extension"
    [ "${debug:-}" ] && echo "DEST_ARCHIVE: $dest_archive"

    [ ! -d "$newdir_path" ] && {
        if [ "${debug:-}" ]; then
            echo "Would create $newdir_path"
        else
            mkdir -p "$newdir_path"
            log "Created directory: $newdir_path"
        fi
    }

    [ ! -f "$dest_archive" ] && {
        if [ "${debug:-}" ]; then
            echo "Would move $archive to $dest_archive"
        else
            rsync -a --no-owner --no-group --remove-source-files "$archive" "$dest_archive"
            #cp -u --no-preserve=mode,ownership "$archive" "$dest_archive" && rm -f "$archive"
            log "Relocated $archive to $dest_archive"
        fi
    }

    rotates=$(ls -1 "$newdir_path" | wc -l )
    [ "$rotates" -ge 7 ] && {
        oldest=$(ls -t "$newdir_path" | tail -1)
        if [ "${debug:-}" ]; then
            echo "Would delete the oldest archive: $oldest"
        else
            rm -f "$newdir_path/$oldest"
            log "Deleted oldest archive of $base_name : $oldest"
        fi
    }   
done

exit 0
```

---

**Update**

I still don't know why this happens, but finally I decided to run the script by cron few minutes after rotation.

I suspect that this part of my "script.sh" `newdir_name="${base_name%-*}"` is not evaluated well by `logrotate`. But again, it worked as expected if I run it forcefully using `logrotate -fv config`

Comment: Shouldn't be hard to see if "`newdir_name="${base_name%-*}"` is not evaluated well by logrotate. "  - put a `set -x` at the top and check the stderr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that logrotate executes the script using `sh` and my script contains bashishms.

From man page:

> **lastaction/endscript**
>
> The lines between **lastaction** and **endscript** (both of which must appear on lines by themselves) are executed (using **/bin/sh**) ...

In the end, I execute my script via `crontab` few minutes after the logrotate.